# angular build is showing a blank page

Tags: angular, build

I have tried to run my angular project build with **angular-http-server**.
when I run the project, It works. but after the build, it only shows a blank page.

[image]

This is the terminal output

[image]

This is the browser output.

couldn't find any explanation...
Any solutions or ideas to debug would be very helpful. Thank you